# Dgraph in Java. How to run raw string mutation query?

Tags: java, dgraph

I need do be able to run raw string mutation queries without using of newBuilder():

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(newEmployer);
Transaction newTransaction = this.dgraphClient.newTransaction();
Mutation mu = Mutation.newBuilder().setSetJson(ByteString.copyFromUtf8(json.toString())).build();
newTransaction.mutate(mu);
```

I want to run:

```
String email = "ba@a.aa";
String userType = "JOB_SEEKER";
Transaction newTransaction = this.dgraphClient.newTransaction();
String query = 
        "{\n" +
        "    set { \n" +
        "       _:user <label> \"USER\" . \n" +
        "      _:user <userType> \"" + email + "\" . \n" +
        "      _:user <email> \"" + userType + "\" . \n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "}";
Mutation mu = Mutation.parseFrom(ByteString.copyFromUtf8(query));
newTransaction.mutate(mu);
```

But I get the error on run-time: "While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field.  This could mean either that the input has been truncated or that an embedded message misreported its own length."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting N-Quad Triples for mutations in gRPC clients such as dgraph4j, you only need to specify the newline-separated triples themselves and pass them to `Mutation#setSetNquads`. They are not surrounded by `set`. In other words, instead of this:

```
{
  set {
    _:user <label> "USER" .
    _:user <userType> "USER_TYPE" .
    _:user <email> "ba@a.aa" .
  }
}
```

You only need the triples:

```
_:user <label> "USER" .
_:user <userType> "USER_TYPE" .
_:user <email> "ba@a.aa" .
```

Here's how it would look like in your Java code:

```java
String email = "ba@a.aa";
String userType = "JOB_SEEKER";
Transaction newTransaction = this.dgraphClient.newTransaction();
String triples = 
        "_:user <label> \"USER\" .\n" +
        "_:user <userType> \"" + email + "\" .\n" +
        "_:user <email> \"" + userType + "\" .";
Mutation mu =
    Mutation.newBuilder()
        .setSetNquads(ByteString.copyFromUtf8(triples))
        .build();
Assigned assigned = newTransaction.mutate(mu);
```

The first mutation format with `{ set { ... } }` is for HTTP clients, which includes mutations within Dgraph Ratel or with `curl`.

More information about Dgraph mutations is available in the mutation docs: https://docs.dgraph.io/mutations/

Comment: The method setSetNquads(ByteString) is undefined for the type DgraphProto.MutationJ in actual driver

Comment: @AlexKumundzhiev Thanks for clarifying. I updated the answer to use Mutation.newBuilder() instead.

Comment: You are a life saviour . Have been trying to fix this error , finally removed { set {   } } . It worked !

Answer (score 0):

I've found some solution, it is not string but it works.

```
JSONObject query = new JSONObject();
query.put("label", "USER");
query.put("userType", userType);
query.put("email", email);
Mutation mu = Mutation.newBuilder().setSetJson(ByteString.copyFromUtf8(query.toJSONString())).build();
```

Comment: I imagine it from Node.js driver examples. I came from JavaScript world and this is more explicit for me, than Dgraph documentation have.